# Plot dual axis graph using DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
                state   runtime   pixels  segments
0                 Texas  0.079277  1756374     12960
1            California  0.045553  1221211      5129
2          Rhode Island  0.002466     8134      1247
3            Washington  0.016046   339786      6854
4               Alabama  0.009114   214936      1930
5  District of Columbia  0.000799      506       218
6                  Ohio  0.007617   192800      2949
```

I am trying to plot this DataFrame with a dual y-axis along a shared x-axis (runtime)

I have done this with the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import figure, show, legend, ylabel

data = pd.read_excel('runtimes.xlsx')

## create the general figure
fig1 = figure()

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(data[['runtime', 'pixels']].T)

ax1.set_ylabel('Pixels')
ax1.set_xlabel('Runtime (s)')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2.plot(data[['runtime', 'segments']].T)
ax2.set_ylabel('Segments', color='r')
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')
```

Which gives me this graph: 
[image]

There are two problems I am trying to fix:
(1) This plots each row twice when I only want it to plot once - how can I fix this?
(2) How can I add a legend so you can tell which line indicates its proper state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that it is usually easier to be explicit about the columns, instead of allowing pandas to do everything automatically, for these kinds of cases. E.g.

```
ax1.scatter(data['runtime'], data['pixels'])
```

and

```
ax2.scatter(data['runtime'], data['segments'])
```

For a complete example demonstrating this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import figure, show, legend, ylabel

data = pd.DataFrame({'runtime': [0.079277, 0.045553, 0.002466, 0.016046, 0.009114,
                                 0.000799, 0.007617],
                     'pixels':  [1756374, 1221211, 8134, 339786, 214936, 506, 192800],
                     'segments':[12960, 5129, 1247, 6854, 1930, 218, 2949]})

## create the general figure
fig1 = figure()

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(data['runtime'], data['pixels'], label="Pixels", marker='.', color='k')

ax1.set_ylabel('Pixels')
ax1.set_xlabel('Runtime (s)')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2.scatter(data['runtime'], data['segments'], label="Segments", marker='.', color='r')
ax2.set_ylabel('Segments', color='r')
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')
fig1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.225,0.845))
plt.show()
```

[image: Shared X example]

You may also note the legend, you can change the location as you want by changing the `bbox_to_anchor` tuple, [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

---

**Edit**

If you need to color based on state then you can do something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import figure, show, legend, ylabel
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

data = pd.DataFrame({'state':   ["Texas", "California", "Rhode Island", "Washington", 
                                 "Alabama", "District of Columbia", "Ohio"],
                     'runtime': [0.079277, 0.045553, 0.002466, 0.016046, 
                                 0.009114, 0.000799, 0.007617],
                     'pixels':  [1756374, 1221211, 8134, 339786, 214936, 506, 192800],
                     'segments':[12960, 5129, 1247, 6854, 1930, 218, 2949]})

## create the general figure
fig1 = figure()

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
for ii in range(len(data['state'])):
    ax1.scatter(data['runtime'][ii], data['pixels'][ii], 
                label=data['state'][ii], marker='.')
    ax2.scatter(data['runtime'][ii], data['segments'][ii], marker='+')
ax1.set_ylabel('Pixels')
ax1.set_xlabel('Runtime (s)')
legend = fig1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.3,0.845))
m1 = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black', linewidth = 0, marker='.', label='Pixels')
m2 = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black', linewidth = 0, marker='+', label='Segments')
plt.legend(handles=[m1,m2], loc='lower right')


ax2.set_ylabel('Segments', color='r')
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')
plt.show()
```

[image: Example with coloring]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Any ideas why i'm still seeing 12 points there however? I'm expecting to see 6

Comment: @Hana I'm not sure what you mean - there should not be 6 points, there are two different relationships being shown, `runtime` vs `pixels` and `runtime` vs `segments`, each of which creates 6 independent points. You can't reduce them the `segments` and `pixels` value to a single point relative to the `runtime` unless `segments` depends on `pixels` or vice versa. You can however do something like in the edit shown.